# Can I use random forest to do feature selection caret

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret, feature-selection

I am using the caret R package do model training, I am totally new to machine learning.

I don't know if I can use the idea shows below to do feature selection and train a model

My code is shown as below:

The idea is that first I will run random forest in train function, then I will select the top20 important features(based on varImp function),and re-train my data based on these top20 features.

I am not sure if this method works?
1.first I will train a random forest model with all features

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method="cv", 
                     number = 5,
                     summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, 
                     classProbs=T,
                     savePredictions = T)

##################################### train model 
set.seed(1234)
model <- 
  train(Bgroup ~ ., 
        data=all_data, 
        method="rf", preProc=c("center", "scale","nzv"), 
        trControl=ctrl,
        tuneLength = 10,
        metric = "ROC"
  )

#####################################  based on this model, I can get a plot of feature importance 

feature_importance <- varImp(model)


##################################### I only selected top20 important features 
importance_df <- data.frame(feature_importance$importance,feature = rownames(feature_importance$importance))
top20 <- head(importance_df[order(importance_df[,1],decreasing = T),],n=20) %>%
  .$feature %>%
  gsub("`", '', .)  


##################################### top20 data selection
data_top20 <- all_data[,top20] 
data_top20$group <- all_data$Bgroup

##################################### re-train model again based on these 20 features 
set.seed(1234)
model_top20 <- train(group ~ ., 
                                  data=data_top20, 
                                  method="rf", preProc=c("center", "scale","nzv"), 
                                  trControl=ctrl,
                                  tuneLength = 10,
                                  metric = "ROC"
)

### calculate performance 
a <- filter(data_top20$pred, mtry ==4)
confusionMatrix(a$pred,a$obs,positive = "positive")
```

Is the idea okay? I am very appreciated if anyone can give me some suggestions

Comment: This is called a learner importance filter. Using it might be a good choice in some circumstances. The way you are implementing it will lead to overestimation of model performance since you estimate the importance on the whole train set and then use resampling to estimate the performance on the feature reduced training set.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much! I just wanna know which feature is more important to the training dataset. It could be used? Or do you think maybe rfe is a better or more advanced choice for that?

Comment: Which feature selection approach is better depends on the problem (no free lunch). rfe is a wrapper approach to feature selection while Rf importance is a filter approach to feature selection. In order to compare them free (little) of bias you will most likely need to perform nested cross validation and to use filters in a correct way (my first comment points out why you are not using them the correct way introducing data leakage and thus bias in performance estimation).